# How to translate a sentence or word entered from a textarea with vuei18n?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-i18n

I have the following json as an example:

```
{
    "Hello":"Hola"
    "how":"como"
    "You go":"te va"
    "text 4": "texto 4"
    "text 5: "texto 5"
}
```

that will serve me for the translations of the words.
Therefore I have a textarea where I write what I want to translate, it can be only 1 word or it can be several words that form a sentence

```
<v-card-text>
 <v-textarea
 clearable
 clear-icon="cancel"
 label=""
 v-model="txtEspaniol"
 ></v-textarea>
</v-card-text>
```

and I also have a textarea where I will get the output of the translation

```
<v-card-text>
  <v-textarea disabled v-model="txtEnglish"></v-textarea>
</v-card-text>
```

The problem I have is how from the first textarea enter whether it is only 1 word or many words that form a sentence, go and look in my vue18in json file for translations and display them in the second textarea.

Example if in textarea 1 enter: 'Hello' in the second textarea I will get 'Hola" or whether the user enters: 'Hello how text 4 " I will get "Hola como texto 4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second textarea's content is computed from the English text.
A single big RegExp is replacing all occurrences in a single pass (important so it doesn't replace replaced text).

For this dictionary, the RegExp is `Hello|how|You go|text 4|text5`.

Note that it's case-sensitive. Making it case-insensitive would be a bit more complicated than just adding the "i" option on the RegExp.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      txtEnglish: '',
      dictionary: {
          "Hello": "Hola",
          "how": "como",
          "You go": "te va",
          "text 4": "texto 4",
          "text 5": "texto 5"
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    txtEspaniol() {
      return this.translate(this.txtEnglish, this.dictionary)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    translate(str, dict) {
      const regex = Object.keys(dict).map(words => words.replace(/([-[\]{}()*+?.\\^$|#,])/g, '\\$1')).join('|')
      return str.replace(new RegExp(regex, 'g'), matched => dict[matched])
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="app">
     <textarea v-model="txtEnglish"></textarea>
     <textarea :value="txtEspaniol"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear, thank you very much, that has worked for me in a great way, you have a great level, blessings.

Comment: Hello mate, good night. I have had the problem for this translation example: resulting in my json having "good" and "good morning" when I enter "good" it first finds me the translation of "Okay" then when I have finished writing "good morning" the translation is no longer correct because it has first found "Okey" result has been: "Okey days" when it should be "Good Morning"